# currency pegging & FX reserves of central banks

Tags: banks, theory

Any good references on the math behind currency pegging by central banks as a function of:
 - the bank's balance sheet
 - market prices of the 'master' currency...specifically, how the bank traders (try to) ensure the currency to be pegged stays within the float range spec'd? Do they just watch intraday market action and come in with counter-acting orders where needed? Or some more structural way?

This harkens back to Soros & BoE, but I'm taking interest moreso from recent comments by Kyle Bass about Hong Kong's balance sheets vs USD.

Comment: In the Economics literature they have developed (theoretical) models of Speculative Attacks https://sites.hks.harvard.edu/fs/jfrankel/API120/ls/L25SpeculativeAttacks.pdf    n  The idea is that once the market expects that the FX reserves are not going to last forever, it becomes rational for "everyone" to sell the currency and the reserves are depleted very quickly. These models are not useful for detailed prediction, but they explain the fundamental nature of currency crises, their suddenness and rapid development for ex.

Comment: Hong Kong CB has history of successfully defending currency. Many predictions of devaluation over the past decades, **never** happened.

Comment: Skeptical view of Kyle Bass' HKD trade here https://www.bloomberg.com/opinion/articles/2019-05-22/kyle-bass-s-hong-kong-dollar-short-fails-history-test

Comment: good piece about Soros and the BOE: https://priceonomics.com/the-trade-of-the-century-when-george-soros-broke/